# ubuntu 16.10 or 16.04.1 working hardly

Tags: 16.10

My laptop is HP Compaq 6715b 
From ver 16.04 Ubuntu work hardly and lagging and fan is a noise

I can't use Ubuntu or any Linux based on it now! 
Any help ?